# Why does the column space equal $\mathbb{R}^m$ (where $m$ is the number of rows) when the rank $= m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $m$ be the number of rows and $n$ be the number of columns. I read that if the rank of some matrix $A$ is equal to $m$, then we know that $Ax=b$ is solvable for every $b$. I believe this means that the column space spans all of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

But I have not been able to come up with a proof to show that rank$(A) =m\Rightarrow C(A)=\mathbb{R}^m$, where $C(A)$ denotes the column space of $A$. Can someone give me the intuition behind why this is be true? The rank is defined based off the rows, so how can it can say anything about the columns?

Comment: Hint: Rank-nullity formula.

Comment: @Chrystomath Oh yes I know that, rank of a matrix minus the dimension of its nullspace equals the number of columns... but not sure how I can apply it here

Comment: What's your definition of rank of a matrix? Besides, whe you wrote “$\operatorname{rank}(A)\Rightarrow C(A)=\Bbb R^m$”, I suppose that you meant to write “$\operatorname{rank}(A)=m\Rightarrow C(A)=\Bbb R^m$”.

Comment: Rank of a matrix is both the dimension of the row space and the dimension of the column space. The proof depends on the exact course of linear algebra you are studying. E.g. one can prove that elementary operations on columns (which don't change the "column" rank) don't change the "row" rank either. Or, one can prove that any of the two ranks also coincides with the size of the largest nonzero minor (i.e. nonzero determinant of the square submatrix of the largest size). It is a bit hard to give the proof that fits your curriculum and not risk assuming something that needs yet to be proven.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh you're right I fixed that now, thanks. Also I know the rank of a matrix to be the number of nonzero rows in the RREF form of the matrix

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you I can try doing some googling based on what you said. For the minor, I did see that term come up in laplace expanasion, but can you clarify a bit? Are you saying the rank is equal to the size of the largest square submatrix with a nonzero determinant? I did not see that definition anywhere but that is very interesting

Comment: @ZackHelms Correct. It is not really a definition, it is a theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you a sketch of how we proved equality of the row rank and the column rank of any matrix on a course of linear algebra I studied a long time ago. Your mileage may vary. (For example, in your course some steps may not work, because they are underpinned by theorems which, in your course, you prove *assuming* the equality of the row and the column rank.)

In the proof, we used *elementary operations* on rows/columns of a matrix. I believe these are usually taken to be: (1) Add a row/column multiplied by a scalar $\lambda$ to another row/column; (2) Multiply a row/column by a scalar $\lambda\ne 0$ and (3) Swap two rows/two columns.

**Lemma 1**: Elementary operations on rows (columns) of a matrix don't change the row (column) rank of that matrix.

**Proof** (sketch): Prove that the span of the resulting rows (columns) is contained in the span of the original rows (columns). However, as all elementary operations are invertible, then the opposite inclusion holds. Consequently, the span of the resulting rows (columns) is the same as the span of the original rows (columns). $\blacksquare$

**Lemma 2**: Elementary operations on columns (rows) of a matrix don't change the row (column) rank of that matrix.

**Proof** (sketch): Prove that, if $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ are rows of the matrix $A$, and you choose some of them (say, $A_{i_1},\ldots,A_{i_k}$), then $A_{i_1},\ldots,A_{i_k}$ are linearly independent *if and only if* the resulting rows (after any elementary operation on columns) are linearly independent. (This is then proven in a pedestrian way for each type of elementary operations.) By symmetry, the statement is now also valid for *columns* and elementary operations on *rows*. $\blacksquare$

**Lemma 3**: Using elementary operations on rows *and* columns, every $m\times n$ matrix can be transformed into a canonical matrix of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&1&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&1&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&0\end{bmatrix}$$

with $r$ "ones" on the diagonal ($r\le\min(m,n)$).

**Proof**: Gaussian elimination.$\blacksquare$

**Theorem**: The row rank of any matrix is equal to the column rank of the same matrix, and both are equal to the number of "ones" on the diagonal of any matrix of the above canonical form (obtained from the original matrix via elementary operations), making that number $r$ uniquely determined, and making this canonical form unique.

**Proof**: By Lemma 3, the original matrix can be converted to the above canonical form. By Lemma 1 and 2, the row rank and the column rank of the original matrix are equal to the row rank and column rank of this canonical matrix, respectively. However, obviously the row rank and the column rank of the *canonical* matrix are the same, and both are equal to $r$. Thus, the original matrix's row rank and column rank are the same, and are both equal to $r$.$\blacksquare$

The last Theorem lets us introduce the name "rank of a matrix" as the name for both the row rank and the column rank.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said this was a deeper level than I have encountered so far so I was having trouble finding any relevant proofs, I had seen some of these properties in isolation but seeing the big picture really helped

Answer (score 1):

We can interpret the matrix equation $$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{m1}&\cdots&a_{mn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ as meaning that $\mathbf{x}$ is in the nullspace of $A$ or that it is perpendicular to the row space (it is 'killed off' by all the row vectors, viewed as column vectors). The two -- the nullspace of $A$ and the perpendicular of the row space -- are the same. Hence the *nullity* of $A$ is the same as the complement of the *row rank* of $A$, i.e., $$\textrm{nullity}(A)=n-\textrm{row-rank}(A).$$

By the rank-nullity formula, the nullity is the complement of the dimension of the image of $A$, which is the number of linearly independent columns, i.e., $$\textrm{nullity}(A)=n-\textrm{col-rank}(A).$$ Hence it follows that the column rank and row rank are the same.

Comment: oh wow thank you. I thought column rank and row rank are only the same in square matrices, didn't realize this was also the case for potentially rectangular matrices